# Convergence of this alternating series: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)C^k} = C \log \frac{C+1}{C}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

I "heard" the following formula for any $C \ge 1$:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)C^k} = C \log \dfrac{C+1}{C}$

Is it correct? What would be a proof?

Comment: this is correct

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for your advice, I will follow it. When I wrote the question, I thought it could be weird to include this "big" equation inside the title, but I see now that it wasn't. Next time I will do better. Thanks!!

Comment: As far as LaTeX in titles is concerned, see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles). But basically if you do not use \displaystyle or \dsize, you should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}, |r|<1$

Integrate both sides, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k}r^{k+1}=-\log(1-r), |r|<1$

Divide r ,$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k}r^{k}=-\frac{\log(1-r)}{r}, |r|<1$

Plug $r=-\frac{1}{C}$ you get
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)C^k} = C \log \dfrac{C+1}{C}, \forall C>1$

We can do all these things because the series is uniformly convergent in its radius of convergence.

Then we check above result for $C=1$, since the alternating harmonic series is convergent, we can plug in $r=-1$ to our series representation of $-\frac{\log(1-r)}{r}$ to get the value of the series by Abel's theorem for power series.

Hence we proved the claim.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the great and quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Taylor expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20ln%281%2Bx%29) of function $\ln(1+x)$ at $0$ and put $x=\frac{1}{C}$. The series:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

converges when $|x|<1$, so also for $X=\frac{1}{C} < 1$.